# Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'oli.OpportunityId' at line 6 column 80

Tags: apex, code

here i am trying to fetch opportunity lookup id from opportunityLineItems bt getting this error.-

> Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'oli.OpportunityId' at
>   line 6 column 80

can anyone please help me

```
public Class Procuct_Adding_To_Order
{

   public static void productOrder(List<OpportunityLineItem> oli){

    List<Order> ord = [Select id from Order where opportunityId IN: oli.OpportunityId];

    for(OpportunityLineItem o : oli)
    {
      OrderItem op = new OrderItem();
      op.OpportunityId = oli.OpportunityId;
      op.ListPrice = oli.ListPrice;
      op.orderId = ord.id;
      op.Product2Id = oli.Product2Id;
      op.ProductCode = oli.ProductCode;
      op.Quantity = oli.Quantity;
      op.TotalPrice = oli.TotalPrice;
      ord.add(op);      
    }
       insert ord;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you need to add colon after IN

you may need to use like

```
public static void productOrder(List<OpportunityLineItem> oli){
    set<Id> setOppId = new set<Id>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem obj: oli){
        setOppId.add(obj.OpportunityId);
    }
    List<Order> ord = [Select id,EffectiveDate from Order where opportunityId IN: setOppId ];

   }
```

---

Updates change `oli` to `o`. `oli` is a list and `o` is a single record so you can just write list.fieldName. You need to write record.FieldName.

Same for `ord`

```
public static void productOrder(List<OpportunityLineItem> oli){ 
    set<Id> setOppId = new set<Id>(); 
    for(OpportunityLineItem obj: oli){ 
        setOppId.add(obj.OpportunityId); 
    } 
    map<Id, Id> mapOpportunityIdToOrderId = new map<Id, Id> ();
    for(Order ord: [Select id, opportunityId from Order where opportunityId IN: setOppId])
    {
        mapOpportunityIdToOrderId.put(ord.opportunityId, ord.Id);
    }
    List<OrderItem> orderIt = new List<OrderItem>(); 
    for(OpportunityLineItem o : oli) 
    { 
        OrderItem op = new OrderItem(); 
        op.OpportunityId = o.OpportunityId; 
        op.ListPrice = o.ListPrice;
        if(mapOpportunityIdToOrderId.containsKey(o.opportunityId))
            op.orderId = mapOpportunityIdToOrderId.get(o.opportunityId);
        op.Product2Id = o.Product2Id; 
        op.ProductCode = o.ProductCode; 
        op.Quantity = o.Quantity; 
        op.TotalPrice = o.TotalPrice; 
        orderIt.add(op); 
    } 
    insert orderIt; 
}
```

Comment: now getting this error---  Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<OpportunityLineItem> at line 6 column 82

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM check my updated ans

Comment: dude again now it's giving the same error -- Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<OpportunityLineItem> at line 6 column 69 
 Please check my updated code

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM inside for loop don't use `oli` instead use only `o`. `oli` is a list and `o` is a single record so you can just write list.fieldName. You need to write record.FieldName.

Comment: ya i have done that , that was such a stupid mistake i have done but still i ma having same error.

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<OpportunityLineItem> at line 6 column 69

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM Yeah same mistake again `ord.id;` here `ord` is a list

Comment: but i want that order id so i thought i can access it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35331/discussion-between-ratan-and-ravi-gautam).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a map to establish a link between the order and the product depending on the opportunity common between them.

then cycle through a loop to assign only the id of the order in question to the respective opportunity

if you want a common order try using LIMIT 1 in the query and return the value to an order variable.

Feel free to chat for further queries :)

Regards A.S.